# Remove sku number from order email

Tags: magento-1.7

I am completely new to magento & using version 1.7. I want to remove sku number from the order email when customer place an order. After lot of R&D I noticed that, the template used is from `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items.phtml` and product name, sku number, quantity and price comes from `echo $this->getItemHtml($_item)` this line. I am not exactly figure out, how should I remove sku number column from this single line? Or is there any other way to do so?

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove this line from `email/order/items.phtml`.

```
<th align="left" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px"><?php echo $this->__('Sku') ?></th>
```

This will remove the column header.
Then remove this

```
 <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px; border-bottom:1px dotted #CCCCCC;"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getSku($_item)) ?></td>
```

from

1. `email/order/items/order/default.phtml`.
2. `downloadable/email/order/items/order/downloadable.phtml`
3. `bundle/email/order/items/order/default.phtml`

This will remove the sku. column for each row.
But don't edit the core files. Copy the files to your theme first.

Comment: thanks for reply. I new to magento and using the default theme. Can u please elaborate, where should I need to copy these files?

Comment: @SandyK. I think this will explain better than I can ever do it. http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/working-with-magento-themes

Comment: In case you're using an extension that overrides emails, as in my case, I'm using Delivery Time extension. So the file I need to edit is at: app/design/frontend/base/default/template/magecheckout/deliverytime/order/email.‌​phtml